# Upload textdocument to WSO2 Governance registry 5.4.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I'm using GREG 5.4.0 and want to upload a simple word/text/pdf document as an asset. I tried uncommenting the document asset as described [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance520/Adding+Other+In-built+Assets) but the asset doesn't show as an option in the publisher.

How do I upload a simple text document to GREG?

Comment: Could you let me know how to reproduce this step by step.

Comment: @thusharaK Nothing to reproduce really. I'm in need of instructions on how to upload a text-document to GREG-publisher. I tried removing document asset as described here: https://docs.wso2.com/display/Governance520/Adding+Other+In-built+Assets But there is still no document asset showing in the publisher. How can i upload a text-document in publisher so that it will be visible in the store?

Comment: What kind of a text document is this? is it .txt ? if you want to upload it in the same format you need to create a registry handler and some more.

Comment: I would like to upload a pdf. Ok where do I find info about creating a registry handler and what more do i need to do? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create below stuff,

1. Create a registry handler.
2. SOLR indexer for PDF files.
3. RXT - content type rxt such as WSDL, WADL
4. Publisher extension.
5. Store extension.(if needed)

Comment: Thank you. In fact no registry handler was needed and SOLR indexer for pdfs already existed. So RXT-definition, publisher extension and store extension was sufficient.